# Why React does't compare Previous State and New State before re rendering? Why it always render when setState is called?

Tags: reactjs

If React compares (Shallow) previous state and next state before re-rendering, it will reduce many renders which helps to optimize performance.

According to [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), React always render component and their children when the setState method is called. Should React smartly handle unwanted re-rendering of a component and their children.

Comment: react has a option available for that It just depend on developer whether to use that option or not.

Comment: *"Why it always render when setState is called?"* Because that's the safer option by default. People may not be updating their state correctly (e.g. `var users = this.state.users; users.push(...); this.setState({users});`) and then their component wouldn't rendered and they would be confused. Once you understand how it update it correctly you can use `PureComponent` or implement the correct lifecycle method.

Answer (score 5):

React can be used with Immutable or plain Javascript data. And React does provide for a lifecycle hook(`shouldComponentUpdate`) which you can choose to use in order to prevent re-render. However for a plain Javascript data sometimes it can be an overhead to compare data and decide whether to re-render the data or not since it may so happen that in order to check for data change, you may need to deep compare the data and in cases where most often a re-render is needed, react has to make the DOM updates after a comparison state which may be more costly then simple Virtual DOM diffing and updating.

That being said, you can achieve a tradeoff between a quick decision of whether to re-render or not actually rendering using a [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) and/or `ImmutableJS` data.

Comment: you can use PureComponent with plain JS data and it will do a shallow comparison...

Comment: @Aprillion, yes we can do that. I think I should have written `PureComponent` and/or ImmutableJS data

Comment: Hey @ShubhamKhatri It means If I am using Immutable Js data or i update store immutably then there is advisable to use Pure Component everywhere as Pure component doesn't re-render when their props doesn't change even if its parent component re renders. Do you agree?